# htaccess rewrite directory up one level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

here is my current htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex main.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ main.php/$1 [QSA,L]

SetEnvIf MFW_ENV ^$ MFW_ENV=local

php_flag short_open_tag On
php_value memory_limit "2G"
php_value upload_max_filesize "2G"
php_value post_max_size "2G"
```

i have my **htaccess** on:

```
/project/web/
```

i have **files** on my

```
/project/local
```

which i want to be available to access when i access

```
/project/web/local
```

i am doing this so when i access

```
website.com/local/file.zip
```

i can access the one on:

```
/project/local/file.zip
```

instead. which is up one level from my web directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule in `/project/web/.htaccess:`

```
SetEnvIf MFW_ENV ^$ MFW_ENV=local

php_flag short_open_tag On
php_value memory_limit "2G"
php_value upload_max_filesize "2G"
php_value post_max_size "2G"

DirectoryIndex main.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/web/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(local/.*)$ /project/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ main.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: when i used this i got 'Internal Server Error', ive added my current htaccess do you think there is a problem with my current htaccess appending to yours?

Comment: Try updated rules in answer. If it doesn't work then check Apache error.log and also tell what is full URL you entered in browser

Comment: [pid 7543] [client 127.0.0.1:58695] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://local.website.com/  | im accessing http://local.website.com/app?id=103

Comment: Am I getting right? How is `local.website.com/app?id=103` related to your question. Didn't you say you want to use URL like `http://local.website.com/project/web/local/file.zip` ?

Comment: ok you've might misunderstood something, im currently getting errors on every page im accessing except the home page so posted a link which doesn't work anymore. what i wanted was to access my files via: http://website.com/local/WYAZkNEFGAcdjre1.apk which i can normally access when the file is under /project/web/local/WYAZkNEFGAcdjre1.apk which i moved to /project/local.

Comment: this is the actual url: http://website.com/local/WYAZkNEFGAcdjre1.apk if i want to download WYAZkNEFGAcdjre1.apk

Comment: the problem is i moved the folder up one level from '/project/web/local' to '/project/local' and now im not able to access them. i dont know if it helps but /project/web is actually a web root directory

Comment: Are you getting 404 while using `http://website.com/local/WYAZkNEFGAcdjre1.apk`? Are there other .htaccess files in the system?

Comment: there is only 1 htaccess.

Comment: There were 2 parts of my question

Comment: im getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Comment out new rule I suggested and retest

Comment: its working fine if i revert back to my past configs, though if the file is not existing i get 500 internal server error.

Comment: That means some existing configuration issue is there. Check in your server configuration if there are any rules are ErrorDocumemt directives.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `../` is not an option in the `.htaccess` file, have the server continue to redirect until it reaches the root. This does a full redirect up one level until it can find a directory or file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Remember that the first `(.*)` is everything before the final 2 slashes (in this case). It reads like it's the first directory, but it's not. And this is using `DirectorySlash Off` so adjust accordingly.

You can see in your dev tools Network that it goes from `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/someFile.html` to `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` to `/dir1/dir2/dir3` and so on.

This is a good use case for `302` redirects for `404 Not Found` assets so that the browser doesn't cache the final URL, and this will avoid returning whatever parent directory even once the file is present.